# How to avoid encoding null (\u0000) when reading from InputStream

Tags: java, string, inputstream, decode

I am reading a request body and put it into an input stream. While I am explicitly saying the decode method, I still get many \u0000 (Null) after the string.

```
InputStream is = exchange.getRequestBody();
byte[] header = new byte[100];
is.read(header);
String s = new String(header, "UTF-8");
```

How can I avoid this with Standard Java Library? I cannot use third party libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is.read(header); returns the number of bytes that were actually read. Change your code as

```
byte[] header = new byte[100];
int n = is.read(header);
String s = new String(header, 0, n, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `BufferedReader` with `InputStreamReader`. I.e.

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = br.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a buffered reader to read it line by line:

```
InputStream is = exchange.getRequestBody();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    // do work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the value of `line.toCharArray()`, you will see that the `null` (aka `'\u0000'`) chars show up.  A round-about solution to getting rid of those is to add only the chars that you want to another array by using an if statement to exclude the `'\u0000'` chars.  So:

```
public String removeNullChars(String line) {
    String result = "";

    // Convert to char array.
    char[] chars = line.toCharArray();

    // Add only chars that are not equal to '\u0000' to result
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] != '\u0000') {
            result += chars[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```